# Xbuntu 18.04.5 install need to add wireless capabilitiy

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I have an old eMachines desktop that was running Vista. I installed Xbuntu 18.04.5 after trying Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and 21.10 neither would boot from the cd which I believe the machine does not have 64bit. The Xbuntu fired right up and the install was easy.

I then tried to access Network Manager which was not available so I am now trying to establish a wireless connection manually. I have a Dell Wireless 1450 Dual-band adapter that hopefully I can use. I see it listed after completing the command: lsusb

Bus 002 Device 007:  ID 413c:8104 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 1450 Dual-band (802.11a/b/g) Adapter) Intersil ISL3887

I found the following instructions (see below) and downloaded what was suggested for the 2nd gen device lm87.arm - https://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-usb/2.13.25.0.lm87.arm

I completed the steps the best I could but have yet to receive the desired results. I am not sure of the line: /lib/firmware/"YOUR_KERNEL_VER_HERE"/"YOUR DOWNLOADED FIRMWARE HERE"

After browsing through the file system I do not know if this should be present or if I need to create a folder titled 5.4.0-42-generic (found after completing the command uname -r)?

Here is the link to the instructions I found under ubuntu forums: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1477646&p=9304551#post9304551

*May 15th, 2010#4Sintar Sintar is offline
First Cup of Ubuntu
Join Date
Feb 2010
Beans
1
Red face Re: Dell Wireless 1450 Wireless USB Adapter
so i'm assuming that you want the native drivers not a ndis wrapper. that you have a usb wifi adapter 1450. not a 1450 studio laptop.
first off go to this web site
http://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/
download a firmware for your device i would suggest one from the usb list twords the bottom they probably have less bugs
1st gen device get a firmware ending in lm86.arm
2nd gen device get one ending in lm87.arm
i used the very bottom one from the usb section since i have a second gen device now rename the firmware you downloaded to
isl3886usb for the 1st gen or
isl3887usb for the 2nd gen
now move it to
/lib/firmware/"YOUR_KERNEL_VER_HERE"/"YOUR DOWNLOADED FIRMWARE HERE"
for 64 bit you might as well put one here too
/lib64/firmware/"YOUR_KERNEL_VER_HERE"/"YOUR DOWNLOADED FIRMWARE HERE"
the syntax to move is
sudo mv /Source/directory/filename /dest/dir/filename
once the files are moved
run
modprobe -r p54usb | modprobe -r p54common
then
modprobe p54usb | modprobe p54common
now iwconfig
it should list your adapter then connect and have a good day*

Your assistance is much appreciated.

I ran the commands as suggested. Not sure of what to do next:

```
$ `sudo modprobe p54usb` 
$ `dmesg | grep p54` 
   [11269.753346] p54usb 2-3:1.0: failed to initialize device (-2) 
   [11269.761600] usbcore: registered new interface driver p54usb
```

Comment: You've provided no specifics as to your hardware; but I used hardware as old as from 2006 in QA *testing* all releases up to and including current *jammy* (older devices up to 19.04).  Windows XP was sold on 32-bit hardware; Vista & later is rare as usually the 32-bit windows was sold on 64-bit hardware (32-bit windows dropped the price by $5 which consumers understood more than 32 vs. 64 bits).  Given the errors in what you provided; I'd check your machine can't use *amd64*.

Comment: FYI:  Xubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* only had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Xfce (*not Xubuntu*).

Comment: The driver for your device is *p54usb*. Load it from the terminal: `sudo modprobe p54usb` and check the message log to see what is says about firmware: `dmesg | grep p54` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I will pursue the other comments related to a potential upgrade to a supported version. I ran the commands as suggested. Not sure of what to do next: 
dseals@dseals-xubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe p54usb
dseals@dseals-xubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep p54
[11269.753346] p54usb 2-3:1.0: failed to initialize device (-2)
[11269.761600] usbcore: registered new interface driver p54usb

Answer (score 1):

In your dmesg, we see:

> p54usb 2-3:1.0: failed to initialize device (-2)

Although missing firmware is not explicitly mentioned, I assume that the required firmware, which is not present in the default Ubuntu installation, is the reason for failure to initialize.

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo wget https://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-usb/2.13.25.0.lm86.arm
sudo mv 2.13.25.0.lm86.arm isl3886usb
sudo wget https://daemonizer.de/prism54/prism54-fw/fw-usb/2.13.25.0.lm87.arm
sudo mv 2.13.25.0.lm87.arm isl3887usb
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep p54
```